# RequestSpecでContent-Typeヘッダapplication/jsonをデフォルトにするには？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Web APIでのデータの送受信形式にJSONを使用し、リクエストのContent-Typeヘッダをapplication/jsonに指定する場合、RequestSpecで以下のように書いてます。

しかし、この書き方だと`spec`ファイル毎に`let(:request_header)`の記入が必要なため、DRYじゃないし、面倒です。
これをデフォルト設定にする、もしくは汎用的に書く方法を知っている方いたら教えて下さい。

```
describe 'Users' do

  let(:request_header) do
    { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json' }
  end

  describe 'POST /api/v1/users' do
    it 'creates a new user' do
      params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)

      expect {
        post '/api/v1/users', params.to_json, request_header
      }.to change { User.count }.from(0).to(1)

      expect(response.status).to eq(201)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記のissueでも同じような質問が挙げられていますが、完全な自動化は難しいようですね。

[ability to add header on every request spec · Issue #1209 · rspec/rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1209)

僕だったら、ショートカット用のメソッドをモジュールとして定義し、request spec全体でincludeするかなーと思います。

```
# spec/support/api_macros.rb
module ApiMacros
  def post_as_json(path, parameters = nil, headers_or_env = {})
    post path, parameters, headers_or_env.merge('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json')
  end

  # 必要に応じてpost以外のバージョンも定義
end

# spec/rails_helper.rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
# ...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include ApiMacros, type: :request
end

# spec/requests/users_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
describe 'Users', type: :request do
  describe 'POST /api/v1/users' do
    it 'creates a new user' do
      params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)

      expect {
        post_as_json '/api/v1/users', params.to_json
      }.to change { User.count }.from(0).to(1)

      expect(response.status).to eq(201)
    end
  end
end
```

完全な自動化が無理な以上、落としどころはこんなところではないでしょうか。

### 追記

prependを使うともうちょっとスマートになるかもです。

```
# spec/support/api_macros.rb
module ApiMacros
  def post(path, parameters = nil, headers_or_env = {})
    super path, parameters, headers_or_env.merge('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json')
  end

  # 必要に応じてpost以外のバージョンも定義
end

# spec/rails_helper.rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
# ...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.prepend ApiMacros, type: :request
end

# spec/requests/users_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
describe 'Users', type: :request do
  describe 'POST /api/v1/users' do
    it 'creates a new user' do
      params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)

      expect {
        post '/api/v1/users', params.to_json
      }.to change { User.count }.from(0).to(1)

      expect(response.status).to eq(201)
    end
  end
end
```

### 追記2

`json: true`みたいなタグを付けて、jsonリクエストを使うかどうか制御するバージョンも作ってみました。

```
# spec/support/api_macros.rb
module ApiMacros
  def post(path, parameters = nil, headers_or_env = {})
    headers_or_env = headers_or_env.merge('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json') if @_json
    super path, parameters, headers_or_env
  end

  # 必要に応じてpost以外のバージョンも定義
end

# spec/rails_helper.rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
# ...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.prepend ApiMacros, type: :request

  config.before do |example|
    @_json = example.metadata[:type] == :request && example.metadata[:json]
  end
end

# spec/requests/users_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

# json: trueが付くと、jsonでリクエストを投げる
describe 'Users', type: :request, json: true do
  describe 'POST /api/v1/users' do
    it 'creates a new user' do
      params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)

      expect {
        post '/api/v1/users', params.to_json
      }.to change { User.count }.from(0).to(1)

      expect(response.status).to eq(201)
    end
  end
end
```

### 追記3

getやdeleteなど、post以外のメソッドも自動的にJSONでリクエストできる仕組みを考えてみました。
ちょっと強引ですが、 ActionDispatch::Integration::Session#process と ActionDispatch::Integration::Runner#reset! にモンキーパッチを当てています。
追記2と同様、spec側では `json: true` のタグでJSONリクエストを使うかどうか制御できます。

```
# spec/support/json_process.rb
module JsonProcess
  def process(method, path, parameters = nil, headers_or_env = nil)
    headers_or_env = (headers_or_env || {}).merge('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json') if @_json
    super method, path, parameters, headers_or_env
  end
end

# spec/rails_helper.rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
# ...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.before(:example, :json => true) do
    def reset!
      @integration_session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(app)
      @integration_session.instance_variable_set("@_json", true)
    end
  end
end
ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.prepend JsonProcess

# spec/requests/users_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

# json: trueが付くと、jsonでリクエストを投げる
describe 'Users', type: :request, json: true do
  describe 'POST /api/v1/users' do
    it 'creates a new user' do
      params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)

      expect {
        post '/api/v1/users', params.to_json
      }.to change { User.count }.from(0).to(1)

      expect(response.status).to eq(201)
    end
  end
end
```

動作確認時のバージョン

- Rails 4.2.4
- rspec-rails 3.3.3

Comment: 実装例たくさん上げていただいて、ありがとうございます。
個人的に `json: true` の実装が好きなので、こちらで対応してみます。

ありがとうございました！